# ubuntu 22.04 after upgrade Youtube is not working

Tags: youtube, 22.04

[youtube is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLxBr.png)

*I have checked github.com also. it is not working. Why it is so? However, when I change DNS to cloudware it is working. Why it is not working by default?*

Comment: Probably something is wrong with ISP. These sites use ipv6.